# Determining the size of a UIView at a given orientation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

I need to calculate a UILabel's height when the device rotates, so I can adjust its frame in order to set the appropriate height needed to display its text.

I want the resetting of the frame to be as smooth as possible, which is why I tried to do the calculation and framesetting in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method.
In this method, however, the bounds of the UILabel's superview are still valid for the old orientation.

When I do the same calls in the didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration: method the framesetting isn't very smooth and feels kinda sluggish (but at least I can do the proper calculations using the superviews bounds.width).

Now to my question: Is there a way to determine the width of a UIView at a given InterfaceOrientation so I can do the calculation described above? I want to do this as generic as possible since I will use the code on both the iPad and the iPhone.

If this is not possible, is there an elegant way to do what I've described above?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds a lot as if you got the solution already. How about using willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and calc the superview frame coordinates manually within that method, based on the upcoming interface orientation (not setting, just calculating) for adjusting the subview (label) frame.

Comment: That's where I'm basically stuck at – how do I calculate the superview's size correctly – regarding the fact that it could be displayed on an iPhone, an iPad or even as a subview of another view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass UIView for your main view and override layoutSubviews.  The will/didRotate interfaces aren't real useful.